# SQ LITE get sub string of column based on index

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to get the sub string of column based on index in sqlite. For example i have a column named as **ID** like **100P_10** . I want to get the Number after **'_'** . currently i am using following query to get this. But i am sure this is not the correct way to do it. Please Help me to solve this.

```
select max(CAST( (case when substr(ID,1,1)  is '_' then  substr(ID,1+1) when substr(ID,2,1)  is '_' then  substr(ID,2+1) when substr(ID,3,1)  is '_' then  substr(ID,3+1) when substr(ID,4,1)  is '_' then  substr(ID,4+1) when substr(ID,5,1)  is '_' then  substr(ID,5+1)when substr(ID,6,1)  is '_' then  substr(ID,6+1) when substr(ID,7,1)  is '_' then  substr(ID,7+1) else ID end) as integer)) from student
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast(substr(a, instr(a, '_') + 1) as integer) from A;
```